# Preposition+Object?

Tags: prepositions, objects

Hi saw this online and was wondering about object following a preposition.

"Common verbs that are followed by at + object are: glance, look, laugh, smile, stare, rejoice etc.
Ex:
She smiled at me. (me is object)."

Is this correct? Or is 'at me' an adverbial? Thanks!

Comment: Not *or*, but *and*.  The "me" is the object of the "at", *and* the "at me" is an adverbial modifier of "smiled".

Comment: The *at* in *smiled at* is not that closely associated with the verb as the online advice suggests. Even *arrived at* is common, but works like this: "Pat [arrived][at the station], not [arrived at][the station]. So, [smiled] [at me], or [smiled][in a way], or [smiled][with such grace].

Comment: That's incorrect. The preposition phrase "at me" is not an adverbial but **complement** of the verb "smiled". Within the PP, "at" is head and "me" is its object.

Comment: @BillJ *That's incorrect.* I think you mean *"some grammars see this differently."* ;)

Comment: @Greybeard  No, I don't mean that. The PP qualifies as a complement because "at" is grammatically selected by the verb. Adjuncts (adverbials) are semantically concerned with the circumstances of the situation -- they express such meanings as manner, spatial or temporal location, duration, condition, and so on. By contrast, the entities involved typically equate to the syntactic complements.

Comment: @BillJ * No, I don't mean that.* Then how do we explain that {preposition + substantive} results in a modifier? If your chosen grammar dictates your explanation as the one truth, then it is a balanced approach to acknowledge that other grammars do not use this explanation. Let me suggest that "at me" can be (i) a complement (ii) an adjunct (iii) a prepositional phrase (iv) a modifier (v) an adverbial.

Comment: Your mistake is in conflating category and function. While complement, adjunct (adverbial) and modifier are functions, preposition phrase is a phrase category, like noun phrase, adjective phrase etc. "At me" is of course a PP (that's its category) and PPs can function as modifiers, but for the reasons I gave above, it's a complement in the OP's particular example.